# Random Seed Recursive Function. How do I do it?

Tags: c#

I have a recursive function, and within the function a random element from an array is selected, but no matter what I do I keep getting the same seed.

```
static Random rand = new Random();
public String spintaxParser(String s)
    {
        if (s.Contains('{'))
        {
            int closingBracePosition = s.IndexOf('}');
            int openingBracePosition = closingBracePosition;

            while (!s[openingBracePosition].Equals('{'))
                openingBracePosition--;

            String spintaxBlock = s.Substring(openingBracePosition, closingBracePosition - openingBracePosition + 1);

            String[] items = spintaxBlock.Substring(1, spintaxBlock.Length - 2).Split('|');


            s = s.Replace(spintaxBlock, items[rand.Next(items.Length)]);

            return spintaxParser(s);
        }
        else
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
```

What's the best way to handle Random in a recursive function?

Comment: Did you try searching for an answer to this? There are so many question on the topic of using Random - for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855756/random-number-generation-same-number-returned (which itself refers to other related questions).

Comment: We'll need some source code to really be able to help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I keep getting the same seed"? Could you provide an example of input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: IMO with your current code it's impossible to get same seed except items count is equal or smaller than 1.

Answer (score 3):

Declare a single (static) instance of the `Random` object outside the scope of your recursive function, then invoke the instance from inside your recursive function.

The default constructor of `Random` will automatically seed it with the current timestamp, so you're getting the same values over and over because you're constantly creating a new instance of the `Random` object.

Edit: Also, you could try this, although it's definitely not ideal. I would prefer a single `Random` instance or a static seed over this method.

```
Random r = new Random( Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode() );
```

Comment: would it be possible to create a new instance of the Random class inside the recursive function and pass in a timestamp?

Comment: @SianJakeyEllis you could create a global (static) seed and reuse it in the constructor when creating your random objects. However, that's probably a bit less than ideal efficiency wise.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you posted code. But in the absence of that, I will use my psychic powers and guess that you are using a pattern like this

```
void MyRecursiveFunction() {
  var index=new Random().Next(...);
  ...
}
```

If true, the fix is to change your code so that it does "new Random()" just once and passes it around (or stores it in some appropriate instance variable) rather than constructing a new one every time.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `Random` as a parameter to the recursive function and use the passed instance to get the next value from it each time.

```
public void Recurse(object param, Random rand)
{

  ...
  var val = rand.Next();
  //use the value ... 
  Recurse(obj, rand);
}

Recurse(arg, new Random());
```

Obviously, the recursion will bottom out in some way but this demonstrates the principle.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you include the random object in the recursive function itself. This test should prove that you wont always get the same int.

```
[Test]
    public void TestSpintaxRandom()
    {
        spintaxParser("{|||{|||{|||{|||{|||{|||{|||{|||}}}}}}}}", new Random());
    }

    public String spintaxParser(String s, Random r)
    {
        if (s.Contains('{'))
        {
            var closingBracePosition = s.IndexOf('}');
            var openingBracePosition = closingBracePosition;

            while (!s[openingBracePosition].Equals('{'))
                openingBracePosition--;

            var spintaxBlock = s.Substring(openingBracePosition, closingBracePosition - openingBracePosition + 1);
            var items = spintaxBlock.Substring(1, spintaxBlock.Length - 2).Split('|');

            var next = r.Next(items.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(next);
            s = s.Replace(spintaxBlock, items[next]);

            return spintaxParser(s, r);
        }

        return s;
    }
```