# Adding objects "morg" into the screen in random position in c#

Tags: c#

How do we add each morg from the list of `morgs` into the screen in random position? And then for each `morg` we output a success message.

I am using the `morg` Class in order to place them in random order.

I am using the `petriDish` Class to keep the list of `morg`, and add the `morg` from the list to the screen.

I am using to Simulation Class to keep track of each `morg` and then change their behavior later on.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace NewMorg
 {
    class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        Morg morg = new Morg(0, 0);

        DisplayMorg currentDisplay = new DisplayMorg(morg);
        currentDisplay.Display();

        morg.SetDisplay(currentDisplay);

        simulator sim = new simulator();

        PetriDish dish = new PetriDish();
        dish.AddMorg(morg);

        sim.step();
    }
}
```

// simulator used for `petriDish`

```
class simulator
{
    private PetriDish dish;

    public simulator()
    {
        dish = new PetriDish();
    }

    public void step()
    {           
        foreach (Morg m in dish.morgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS !!!");                
        }                        
    }
}
```

// `petrDish` used for the list of `morgs`

```
class PetriDish
{
    public List<Morg> morgs;

    public PetriDish()
    {
        morgs = new List<Morg>();
    }

    public void AddMorg(Morg m)
    {           
        morgs.Add(m);
    }
}
```

// class containing `morg` attributes

```
class Morg
{
    private DisplayMorg display;

    public Morg(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

    protected int x;
    protected int y;

    public int X { get { return x; } }
    public int Y { get { return y; } }

    public void SetDisplay(DisplayMorg display) 
    { this.display = display; }

    public void SetData(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        if (display != null)
        {
            display.Display();
        }
    }

    public void SetRandom()
    {
        Random x = new Random();
        Random y = new Random();
        this.x = x.Next(1, 101);
        this.y = y.Next(1, 101);

        if (display != null)
        {
            display.Display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) you never asked a question, you just gave us your end goal. What specific problem are you having? 2) don't initialize random inside the method, initialize it in the constructor or pass it in.

Comment: you also dont need 2 random generators

Comment: TL;DR... Make sure to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855756/random-number-generation-same-number-returned