# Error with method arguments that I don't understand

Tags: c#, methods, arguments, return-value

I'm currently taking a class at my high school, that teaches C# and .net framework, python, etc. I have to make a program that plays "Rock, Paper, Scissors" against a person using return-methods as the project for this unit.

I keep running into an error on Microsoft Visual Studios 2015 that says
[No Overload for method 'PCRandomizer' takes 1 arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DGC5.png)

I'm still really new to this whole system so I'm having a hard time understanding this, but my program (so far) is like this;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rock__Paper__Scissors
{
    public partial class rockPaperScissors : Form
    {
        public rockPaperScissors()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    int playerChoice;

    // Variable to indicate what the choice is.
    int pcChoice;

    private int PCRandomizer()
    {


        // Create a Random Object.
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Get the rand integer between 1 and 3.
        // 1 and the PC has chosen Rock.
        // 2 and the PC has chosen Paper.
        // 3 and the PC has chosen scissors.
        pcChoice = rand.Next(1, 3);

        // This returns the value back to the main method.
        return pcChoice;
    }



    private void playerRockPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        playerChoice = 1;

        PCRandomizer(out pcChoice);
    }

    private void playerPaperPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void playerScissorsPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the Form
        this.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

I apologize for the long post, but I'm getting pretty desperate as this is already a day behind schedule and several people in my class also have this issue.

I found this page [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8fa7f853-c3dc-4db1-8810-3bc9b2a91c27/error-cs1501-no-overload-for-method-waitone-takes-1-arguments-?forum=csharpgeneral), but I did not understand it.

Comment: You've defined `PCRandomizer` as taking no arguments. However, you're invoking it: `PCRandomizer(out pcChoice)` with an argument. That's what the error means - it's up to *you* to decide which of the two definitions are correct. However, it's likely you've confused an out parameter with a *return* parameter. You may have wanted to write `pcChoice = PCRandomizer()`

Comment: Thank you guys so much, both of the responses.

Comment: side note: to save you time waiting for question timer reset - here is answer to your next question you are about to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855756/random-number-generation-same-number-returned. Also please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code - sample in the question has way too many unrelated lines.

Comment: @Ander109 If parameter's answer helped you solve the problem - please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So instead of using an `out`, simply set your `pcChoice` variable to the result of `PCRandomizer`.  That method returns the integer, which will be assigned to `pcChoice`.

```
private void playerRockPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    playerChoice = 1;

    pcChoice = PCRandomizer();
}
```